# How can I add vertical and horizontal asterisks and lines to ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a line plot with errorbars in ggplot2 and I would like to add lines and asterisks to show which comparisons were significant. I have done my testing in a different program, so I am looking for something other than "ggsignif" because it wouldn't reflect my significance testing.

This is a minimal example of my code so far:

```
data = structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor"), 
                      factorA = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("circle", "square"), class = "factor"), 
                      factorB = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("blue", "green", "red", "yellow"), class = "factor"), 
                      rating = c(0.4, 0.1, 0.3, 0.7, 0.3, 0.15, 0.5, 0.47, 0.56, 0.34, 0.48, 0.74, 0.60, 0.45, 0.37, 0.57),
                      se = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)), 
                 row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")

pd <- position_dodge(0.1)
ggplot(data, aes(x=factorA, y=rating, colour=group, group=group)) + 
  facet_grid(. ~ factorB) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=rating-se, ymax=rating+se), colour="black", width=.25) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```

And this is kind of what I am looking for:
[image: example]

I am also open to other suggestions how to reflect these significant comparisons:

- no versus yes in the blue and the red condition
- circle versus square in the yellow condition

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts:

1. For specifying comparisons and significance within plots, then `stat_compare_means` from the `ggpubr` package is fantastic. Vignette [here](http://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/reference/stat_compare_means.html) - either with a ggpubr plot (eg `ggline`) or can add to any other ggplot object.

```
# Pairwise comparisons: Specify the comparisons you want
my_comparisons <- list( c("0.5", "1"), c("1", "2"), c("0.5", "2") )
ggboxplot(ToothGrowth, x = "dose", y = "len",
          color = "dose", palette = "npg")+
# Add pairwise comparisons p-value
stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons, label.y = c(29, 35, 40))+
stat_compare_means(label.y = 45)     # Add global Anova p-value
```

2. However more broadly, it's a busy plot (with rating v factorA, facet by factorB and grouped by group) and I'm not sure it's clear which comparisons you are making eg. in facet yellow, the p-val is the aggregate difference between circle & square, but the error bars are circle vs square, subset by group yes/no also

Then within blue and red: appears to be comparing yes v no

Comment: Yes, I agree, I am also not very happy with it. Maybe you have some suggestion? The underlying comparisons are investigating the influence of group and factorA including their interaction on ratings. They are made for every instance of factorB independently. In facet blue, the significant difference is between groups, same for red. In yellow, the significant difference is due to factorA. There are no interactions.